# How crypto token in metamask wallet get stolen by hacker?

Tags: binance-smart-chain

My crypto token which runs in BSC network has just been stolen few hours ago. I looked at the transaction history in my metamask wallet, nothing new in there. So it must be executed remotely. I do not think the hacker got my secret phrase. I never share it to anyone. The only "sharing" I have done is when I import the secret phrase from my linux laptop to windows pc by using SSH. But I visited many dapp sites and approve some of them and left them connected. But AFAIK, approval is specific to a token. Say for example I approve a dapp to spend my token X for certain amount, it should not be able to spend my token Y. Or am I wrong? What methods could possibly be used by the hacker to take over my wallet and transfer tokens to his wallet?

Comment: please share your public address

Comment: Can I contact you privately? I do not want to share my address publicly.

Comment: Sure, but at least you can see if the transaction is coming from your wallet? They invoked transferFrom? Or transfer?

Comment: Do you have a transaction hash of the operation? Without more details we couldn't say anyting, perhaps it is a token with dynamic balances, perhaps it is a scam token.

Comment: My telegram id is abida879. We can continue our chat there.